# How to get expected result from sql table

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table with data::

```html
atm_identifier expected_pickup actual_pickup
ATM1            2019-03-10
ATM1            2019-03-15
ATM1            2019-04-21      2019-04-23
ATM1            2019-04-26
ATM1            2019-05-15
ATM1            2019-05-17      2019-05-17
```

but want to get result as-----

```html
atm start_date end_date
ATM1 2019-03-10 2019-04-23
ATM1 2019-04-26 2019-05-17
```

i am using this sql but not getting the expected output

```html
select ATM_IDENTIFIER , ACTUAL_PICKUP ,  
(Select min(b.EXPECTED_PICKUP)
from ATM_CASH_PICKUP b
where b.ATM_IDENTIFIER = a.ATM_IDENTIFIER
and b.EXPECTED_PICKUP between b.EXPECTED_PICKUP and a.EXPECTED_PICKUP
group by ATM_IDENTIFIER  ) as EXPECTED_PICKUP
from ATM_CASH_PICKUP a
where ACTUAL_PICKUP  is not null
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing a cumulative reverse max to assign a group and then choosing the first row in each group:

```
select atm_identifier, min(expected_pickup), max(actual_pickup)
from (select t.*,
             sum(actual_pickup is not null) over (partition by atm_identifier order by expected_pickup desc) as imputed_actual_pickup
      from t
     ) t
group by atm_identifier, imputed_actual_pickup;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ae8714e1bbc8ff9937ae1af3025f8d9) is a db<>fiddle.  It happens to use MySQL, but this is standard SQL.

Comment: i am getting this
ATM_IDENTIFIER   MIN(EXPECTED_PICKUP)   IMPUTED_ACTUAL_PICKUP  
ATM1  2019-03-10 2019-05-17

Comment: @ram . . . I hate when I do that.  I switched ideas midstream, and left an answer that just wasn't fully formed.  I fixed the answer and added a fiddle.